# ¿Por qué falla este codigo en localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, leaflet, mapquest

Tengo este código sacado de una web, el cual necesito utilizar, he probado a insertarlo en un proyecto en laragon y en un documento suelto en mi localhost, en ningún lugar me funciona, pero sin embargo por casualidad he ejecutado el archivo desde mi escritorio y me funciona perfectamente, no consigo dar con el error..

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-map.js?key=lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24"></script>
  <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-routing.js?key=lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
      
      window.onload = function() {

          console.log(MQ);
          var map,
              dir;

          map = L.map('map', {
              layers: MQ.mapLayer(),
              center: [ 42.346353, -71.415958 ],
              zoom: 9
          });

          dir = MQ.routing.directions();

          dir.route({
              locations: [
                   { country: 'spain', city: 'cordoba' },
                  { country: 'spain', city: 'huelva' },
              ]
          });

          map.addLayer(MQ.routing.routeLayer({
              directions: dir,
              fitBounds: true
          }));
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body style='border:0; margin: 0'>
<div id="map" style='width: 100%; height:530px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya viste que te dice la consola del explorador? con F12 puedes entrar

Answer (score 1):

Ya sé por que no te funciona.

Estás usando dos APIs leaflet y mapquest.

Mapquest no te funciona por que la key que estás usando es la del ejemplo de la página web, tienes que obtener tu key, te la proporciona mapquest, para ello:

Tienes que crearte una cuenta en la página de [MapQuest](https://developer.mapquest.com/plan_purchase/steps/business_edition/business_edition_free/register) que es la API que estás intentando usar, después de crear tu cuenta tienes 15.000 peticiones gratis y nada mas entrar a tu cuenta ya tienes tu API key creada, adjunto foto (tapé la información por privacidad):
[image: imagen con información de panel de apoyo keys]
Vale, ahora copias tu key que está donde dice Consumer Key.

Ahora en los links donde dice MiKey lo remplazas por tu API key:

```
<script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-map.js?key=MiKey"></script>
<script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-routing.js?key=MiKey"></script>
```

Ejemplo para probar (debería de funcionar, no olvides poner tu api key en el ejemplo si lo pruebas):

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-map.js?key=MiKey"></script>
    <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-routing.js?key=MiKey"></script>
</head>

<body style='border:0; margin: 0'>
    <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height:530px;'></div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {

            var map = L.map('map', {
                layers: MQ.mapLayer(),
                center: [40.731701, -73.993411],
                zoom: 12
            });

            var dir = MQ.routing.directions();

            dir.route({
                locations: [{
                        country: 'spain',
                        city: 'cordoba'
                    },
                    {
                        country: 'spain',
                        city: 'huelva'
                    },
                ]
            });

            CustomRouteLayer = MQ.Routing.RouteLayer.extend({
                createStartMarker: function(location, stopNumber) {
                    var custom_icon;
                    var marker;

                    custom_icon = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'https://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/geticon?uri=poi-red_1.png',
                        iconSize: [20, 29],
                        iconAnchor: [10, 29],
                        popupAnchor: [0, -29]
                    });

                    marker = L.marker(location.latLng, {
                        icon: custom_icon
                    }).addTo(map);

                    return marker;
                },

                createEndMarker: function(location, stopNumber) {
                    var custom_icon;
                    var marker;

                    custom_icon = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'https://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/geticon?uri=poi-blue_1.png',
                        iconSize: [20, 29],
                        iconAnchor: [10, 29],
                        popupAnchor: [0, -29]
                    });

                    marker = L.marker(location.latLng, {
                        icon: custom_icon
                    }).addTo(map);

                    return marker;
                }
            });

            map.addLayer(new CustomRouteLayer({
                directions: dir,
                fitBounds: true
            }));
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya tenía la key generada pero estaba cambiándolo en un archivo equivocado, no me había fijado que tenía que ponerla en el enlace, muchísimas gracias de verdad, le había dado muchas vueltas pero al no trabajar nunca con APIS me encontraba un poco perdido!